# Derivative of function with Heaviside Function

Tags: calculus, signal-processing

In attempting to get the differential equation given a transfer function, I need to take through the third derivative of $r(t) = 5t^2 \, u(t)$, where $u(t)$ is the Heaviside function. If I "ignore" the $u(t)$, I can easily get the derivatives ($r'(t)=10 \, t \, u(t)$, $r''(t) = 10 \, u(t)$, $r'''(t)=0$). However, if I consider the $u(t)$, my first derivative becomes $r'(t)=5 \, t^2 \, \delta(t) + 10 \, t \, u(t)$, where $\delta(t)$ is the Dirac Delta Function.

Do I need to consider $u(t)$ when taking the derivative? If so, then what is the derivative of the Dirac Delta Function that I would use to get the second derivative?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: it depends on what you want to do. "differential equation given a transfer function" lets me think that yes you have to differentiate the $\delta(t)$. For example the differential equation $y''(t) - y(t) = x(t)$ is the same as the convolution equation $y \ast h(t) = x(t)$ where $h(t) = \delta''(t) - \delta(t)$, so that $H(s) = s^2-1$

Comment: Strictly speaking, if all you are doing is differentiating $r(t)$, then $r'(t)=10t u(t) + 5t^2 \delta(t),r''(t)=10 u(t) + 20t \delta(t) + 5t^2 \delta'(t)$, and $r'''(t)=30 \delta(t) + 30t \delta'(t) + 10 \delta(t) + 5t^2 \delta''(t)$. In the sense of distribution theory you have that $\delta^{(n)}(f)=(-1)^n f^{(n)}(0)$. Most likely this is indeed what you need to do, in particular this is important when solving linear differential equations by Laplace transform methods.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If it's a Heaviside of $u(t) = 0 $ at $ t < 0 $ and $ u(t) = 1 $ at $ t >= 0 $ 
then it seems to only make physical sense if you ignore the discontinuity below $ t = 0 $ . 
In effect this means ignoring the terms with $ u'(t), u''(t) ... $ etc.

Comment: I completely disagree with this answer; doing this will give you the wrong behavior when dealing with discontinuous forcings in linear ODEs.

Comment: Hadn't thought of that. There, the response before a discrete forcing does affect the subsequent response. Apologies.